# Databricks ODBC driver missing

Tags: linux, databricks

has anyone else encountered this?
I think this driver is missing from repo from today 17.6.2021 onwards.

Anyway to solve this?

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcap2-bin libpam-cap
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  msodbcsql17
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
Need to get 745 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial/main amd64 msodbcsql17 amd64 17.7.2.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 40.114.136.21 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 40.114.136.21 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: I have the same issue with the Debian 10 repository, looks like all the /pool/ folders are gone for all distributions